# Как вывести таблицу на печать корректно?

Tags: javascript, css

Суть проблемы такая, мне нужно вывести на печать таблицу и чтобы она поместилась на одном листе А4. У меня таблица выводится динамически (PHP). При печати у меня выводятся все столбцы. Как сделать так чтобы на печать выводились определенные столбцы и не более того.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/project/print.css">
CSS print.css
@media print {
    table
        {
       background-color: #2196f3;      
    }
}
```

---

```
function PrintElem(elem) 
{ 
    Popup($(elem).html()); 
} 
function Popup(data) 
{ 
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'table', 'height=400,width=600'); 
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>'); 
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >'); 
    mywindow.document.write(data); 
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>'); 
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10 
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10 
    mywindow.print(); 
    mywindow.close(); 
    return true; 
}

<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('#table')" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `media query` для того, что бы при печати применить определенные стили к таблице. В этих стилях и скройте не нужные вам столбцы

```
@media print {
    table .column1 { // column1 замените на нужные вам столбцы
        display: none
    }
}
```

Создайте отдельный файл `print.css` и подключите его на страницу.

Comment: у меня не работает @media print, файл подключил. Но изменений нет.

Comment: @Элиот, на какую страницу подключили то? Которую через `window.open` открываете?

Comment: да, на нее и подключил

Comment: @Элиот, добавьте в вопрос ваш `css` код и то как подключаете файл

Comment: добавил код css.

Comment: @Элиот, вы стили через `link` подключаете, а новое окно для печати создаете программно, попробуйте программно в него вставить `link`

Comment: ThisMan, пробовал не работает все равно(((